# Grub not showing in dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have installed uubuntu 20.04 in a pc with Windows 10 with bios legacy. Grub isn't showing even if I changed grub to display=menu and updated grub. Doing the boot recovery it says:

```
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub2 of
sda5 into the MBR of sda.
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix
```

This is the complate pastebin: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/NZ8gxjwyQQ/

How can I reinstall grub2 as is it said? Also, I cannot access Windows at all because there is no boot screen when turning on, it goes directly to ubuntu.

Update: So, it ended up that GRUB doesn't appear when restarting, but it appears when I turn it off and on. That's strange

Comment: If Windows 10 is installed as a legacy BIOS OS, then you must install Ubuntu that way too. A MBR partition scheme only allows for 4 partitions so legacy BIOS is a poor choice for dual boot. It's a poor choice for Windows too since Windows likes to install 4 partitions all by itself. You're probably going to have to reinstall one or both operating systems so you may as well take this opportunity to use EFI for both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` in grub

Comment: GRUB_TERMINAL=console it's there

Comment: Note that grub only boots working Windows. And Windows will turn fast start up back on with updates & grub will not boot Windows. You then have to temporarily reinstall Widnows BIOS boot loader to MBR, fix Windows, & restore grub to MBR to dual boot. UEFI keeps both boot loaders in ESP. Microsoft has required  vendors to install in UEFI boot mode since 2012. If using BIOS keep both Windows repair flash drive & Ubuntu live installer so you can regularly make repairs to boot loaders. You may need to temporarily turn os-prober on as there is security issue, so it is being turned off, now.